# How to improve a SQL timestamp range query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a table `records` having three fields:

```
id - the row id
value - the row value
source - the source of the value
timestamp - the time when the row was inserted (should this be a unix timestamp or a datetime?)
```

And I want to perform a query like this:

`SELECT timestamp, value FROM records WHERE timestamp >= a AND timestamp <= b`

However in a table with millions of records this query is super inefficient!

I am using Azure SQL Server as the DBMS. Can this be optimised?

If so can you provide a step-by-step guide to do it (please don't skip "small" steps)? Be it creating indexes, redesigning the query statement, redesigning the table (partitioning?)...

Thanks!

Comment: You would seem to want an index on `records(timestamp, value)`.

Comment: what type of index would perform the best on this query?

Comment: Please do some research on indexes.  By asking for each individual small step, you are showing that you have not done any research on query tuning.

Comment: I have looked for some answers but they all have shortcomings... eg: https://explainextended.com/2009/08/11/efficient-date-range-query-sql-server/ this one blows the CTE recursion stack.

Comment: We can't see your tables so how could we help you redesign it? And forget the notion that partitioning is an optimization tool. Partitioning tables does NOT magically make queries faster. IMHO I would make your DateInserted column be a datetime datatype as using a unix timestamp means you have convert it to a meaningful value anyway. And avoid the name timestamp as this a datatype in sql server (but it has nothing to do with datetime information).

Answer (score 1):

After creating an index on the field you want to search, you can use a between operator so it is a single operation, which is most efficient for sql.

SELECT XXX FROM ABC WHERE DateField BETWEEN '1/1/2015' AND '12/31/2015'

Also, in SQL Server 2016 you can create range indexes for use on things like time-stamps using memory optimized tables. That's really the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the datetime, or even better the datetime2 data type to store the date data (datetime2 being better as it has a higher level of precision, and with lower precision levels will use less storage).

As for your query, based upon the statement you posted you would want the timestamp to be the key column, and then include the value. This is because you are using the timestamp as your predicate, and returning the value along with it.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_Records_Timestamp on Records (Timestamp) INCLUDE (Value)
```

This being said, be careful of your column names. I would highly recommend not using reserved keywords for columns names as they can be a lot more difficult to work with.